# show and hide divs on timer

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a list of divs

```
<div id="container_dc">
    <div class="slide" id="slide_1"></div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide_2"></div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide_3"></div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide_4"></div>
</div>
```

Each div has a background image.

I want to show and one div at a time starting with the first, and show each for 4 second before hiding it and showing the next.

I cannot use jquery!

Want it to be as simple as possible.

What is the best way to go about this? any code will be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines:

```
var container = document.getElementById("container_dc"),
    children = container.childNodes,
    show=-1;

window.setInterval(function() {
    if(children[show]) children[show].display='hidden';
    show=show+1;
    if(show==children.length) show=0;
    children[show].display='block';
    next=(next+1);
},4000);
```

*The code is documentation enough.*

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding it above the images, and then below at the bottom of the page, but didn't work, do I need to put a call to it in onload or something?